# Correct animation for changing cells in List/ForEach loop on search in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

The problem I am having with the below code is that when the user searches for a specific contact and I need to change the list from `contacts` to `searchResults` (which contain the same type of `CNContact` element with unique `.identifier`, the animation slides the entire list to the right and bring another one from the left. Surprisingly, this doesn't reproduce in iOS 14, so maybe this is a bug with iOS 13.4?

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        SearchBar(text: $searchViewModel.searchText)
        let displayContacts = searchViewModel.searchText.count == 0 ? contacts : searchResults
        List {
            ForEach(displayContacts, id: \.identifier) { contact in
                cellWithContact(contact)
            }
        }
    }
}

@ViewBuilder
private func cellWithContact(_ contact: CNContact) -> some View {
    let displayName: String? = CNContactFormatter.string(from: contact, style: .fullName)
    HStack() {
        Text(displayName ?? "No Name")
        Spacer()
        Button {
            // invite
        } label: {
            Text("Invite")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Some of the code is missing to minimize complexity; if you need more information, please comment below and I will follow up.